# Is window.open blocking my other lines of javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a game made in vb.net.  I am encountering an issue when using window.open in a javascript section.

Below you can see my .aspx page.

In the script tag near the bottom, you will see this line:

```
window.open('../game/map/?worldID=' + worldID, 'mapdisplay', 'titlebar=yes,width=500,height=900');
```

So this line is working.  When it is reached, it opens the game world.

But the line before it, which is a console.log is never fired.

Additionally, I have some javascript alerts and console.logs in the code behind file, which you can find below.

But those are also never fired.

HOWEVER, this is all very strange to me.  If I comment out the `window.open` line, all the console.logs and alerts do fire!  But of course the new window doesn't open.

Could there be a reason as to why `window.open` is blocking my javascript console.logs and alerts?

.aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="OpenWorldMap.aspx.vb" Inherits="game.OpenWorldMap" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Open World</title>
    <script src="../scripts/world.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="frmOpenGame" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    
    <input type="hidden" name="worldMap" id="worldMap" value="false" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfWorldMap" runat="server" Value="0" />
</body>
        <script>
            const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
            const worldID = urlParams.get('worldID');
            // this console.log line never works unless I comment out the window.open line below it
            console.log("Opening World");
            window.open('../game/map/?worldID=' + worldID, 'mapdisplay', 'titlebar=yes,width=500,height=900');
        </script>
</html>
```

My vb code behind page:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim worldID As Guid
    Dim worldLockedBy As String = ""

    Try
        worldID = New Guid(Request.QueryString("worldID"))
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write("An error has occured")
        Response.End()
    End Try


    worldLockedBy = gme_IsWorldLocked(worldID.ToString)
    
    // none of my alerts or console.logs fire unless I comment out the window.open
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(worldLockedBy) Or worldLockedBy.ToUpper = utils.myUserID Then
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.Page.GetType, "z", "alert('You can now enter this world!');", True)
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.Page.GetType, "z", "console.log('You can now enter this world!');", True)
    Else
        worldLockedBy = gme_IsWorldLocked(worldID.ToString, True)
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.Page.GetType, "z", "alert('This world is full');", True)
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.Page.GetType, "z", "console.log('This world is full');", True)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Your console.log would have happened, it's just you now have opened another webpage, so all the console output would have been cleared.

Comment: @Keith thanks!  I did make sure to quickly open my developer console in the new window but I still never got any alerts or console.logs

Comment: If your using Chrome, there is an option called `Preserve log`, this will stop the log clearing when navigating to new page.  Click the cog in dev console,  the one attached to the console window to bring up the options.

Comment: @Keith I wrapped a `setTimeout()` around the `window.open` and set it to delay 1.5 seconds and it worked!  So odd...I am not sure why this is happening.